# Android ListView width doesn't match parent

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridlayout

I have a problem with my android app markup. I set width in ListView inside GridLayout to `match_parent` and thought it will get in screen size. But in my implementation listView width matches WHOLE SCREEN SIZE and due to left column doesn't fit in screen.

I tried to use TableLayout? but result is the same: ListView width is bigger than I want and goes out of the screen.

What should I change to set ListView width to fit the screen size.
Bellow is my simplified markup.
picture of curren result: https://yadi.sk/d/qh9qOVfmUNqEo (This is my 1st question and doesn't have enough reputation to add image inside question).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.UploadToServerActivity"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayoutId"
        android:columnCount='2'>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/select_image"
            android:id="@+id/selectPhoto"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>


    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:background="#C8C8C8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Try nesting the ListView in a FrameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the layout you want to build, made with the help of a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation and using it's android:weightSum property :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="100">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Select Image" 
        android:layout_weight="55"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C8C8C8"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:layout_weight="45" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you!

But also I was interested in how can I do it with GridLayout, because there will be a lot of buttons and some text in left part right column will be row_spanned .